# Proof verification: Open equivalence classes implies the relation is closed in product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $R$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Then prove that if each equivalence class is open in $X$, then $R$ is closed in $X \times X$ (product topology).

My attempt: Let $(x,y) \in (X \times X) \setminus R$. Since $[x]_R$ and $[y]_R$ are open in $X$, thus $ [x]_R \times [y]_R$ is open in $X \times X$. Furthermore, $[x]_R \times [y]_R \subset (X \times X) \setminus R$, because otherwise $(x,y) \in R$. Thus $R$ is closed.

Please see if I am missing any detail. Thank you.

One thing that seems ''absurd" to me here is that once we proved that $R$ is closed, then it implies that each class is closed also. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757136/is-it-true-that-if-a-given-equivalence-relation-is-closed-then-each-equivalence). Thus if each class is open then it implies each class is clopen.

Comment: You may want to explain more why “because otherwise $(x,y)\in R$” in  the part at the end. But it’s fine overall.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: I am clear with that reason, becasue $R$ is an equivalence relation. I am doubting my proof because once each equivalence class is open then it implies each equivalence class is clopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this proof seems fine. Equivalence classes partition a space, so if each class is open, its complement is the union of all other classes, and therefore open. Since the class is open and its complement is open, the class is both open and closed.

Comment: Thanks! I missed it!